# Laravel Fresh Install - Decrypt Error

Tags: php, laravel, exception, laravel-5

I'm running a fresh laravel 5.4 install, the application key successfully set and to my knowledge setup properly.

Howerver, when I enable XDebug I get the following error:

```
throw new DecryptException('The payload is invalid.');
```

[image: Laravel Throw Decrypt Exception]

$Payload is null, is there any thing i forgot to setup? or can I safely ignore this exception before going into production or how can I fix this? Keep in mind this is a brand new install and `php artisan key:generate` was run

Comment: You should not use XDebug in production

Comment: It is not a production server, it's a virtual machine (ubuntu 16)  but the exception will be thrown even if xdebug is off right? In production xdebug will be off, ofcourse

Comment: You said yourself that it doesn't error when XDebug is off :)
Go through the `validPayload` function and find out what it is that XDebug might be putting in to the code that is causing it's validation to fail. My guess is that it might be throwing some other warning that is not normally thrown without it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This "Decrypter" processes every key/value of the cookies, so you can't actually avoid throwing this DecryptException while debugging. It works for me when I changed the breakpoint config from "everything" to "Notice" only.

[image: Screenshot]